# Delete column if rows fulfill condition

Tags: pandas, if-statement

This is my dataframe:

[image: Dataframe]

If all values of column size_A are below 5, I would like to drop size_A and all other columns that contain '_A' (so in this case height_A). Do all this for size_B, and size_C as well.

I tried:

`

```
names = ['A', 'B', 'C']

for i in names:
    if df_try['size_'+str(i)].all() < 5:
        df_try = df_try.drop(['size_'+str(i), 'height_'+str(i)],axis=1)
```

`
But I get an empty dataframe.

Comment: Change to (df_try['size_'+str(i)] < 5).all()

Answer (score 0):

No need for a loop here. You can use a boolean mask the check the condition over the `"size"` columns then [**`pandas.DataFrame.filter`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to keep only the desired columns.

```
dico_mask= df.filter(regex="^size_").lt(5).all().to_dict()

cols_to_drop = ''.join([suff[-1] for suff in list({k: v for k, v in dico_mask.items() if v==True})])

out = df.filter(regex=f"_[^{cols_to_drop}]$")
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)

   size_B  size_C  height_B  height_C
0       1       1        11        12
1       5       5        11        12
2       4       6        11        12
3       4       0        11        12
4       2       2        11        12
```